# Handle exception if parsing large xlsx file in perl

Tags: excel, perl, parsing, cgi

I want to show pop up if script is not able to parse large xlsx file.

```
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX->new;
my $workbook = $parser->parse("file.xlsx");
```

My perl cgi page got blank, if I submitted large xlsx file.
Here I need to handle if below parse function is not success then will add javascript in catch/finally method to pop up like "invalid file".

```
my $workbook = $parser->parse("file.xlsx");
```

Comment: IF you submit a large file, do you actually get the file? Various frameworks have limits on upload sizes. Back up a few steps to see if the file is completely there and if that is the problem, handle the error there.

Comment: I am submitting that file from perl/CGI page and on server location I am getting that file,because before parsing it I am copying that file on server location.

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel#parse($filename,-$formatter)):

> parse($filename, $formatter)
>
> The Parser parse() method returns a "Workbook" object.

```
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new(); 
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');
```

> If an error occurs parse() returns undef. In general, programs should
> contain a test for failed parsing as follows:

```
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new(); 
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');   
if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}
```

The documentation for the module that you use, [`Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX) points to the main module [`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) for documentation:

> This module is an adaptor for Spreadsheet::ParseExcel that reads XLSX files. For documentation about the various data that you can retrieve from these classes, please see Spreadsheet::ParseExcel, Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook, Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet, and Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Cell.

Comment: thanks, but I already read that, also I am using that. However application itself not moving from this  my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');, So I need to handle this specific line only, it went into halt mode then will handle in catch.

Comment: @Bakli You could edit your question to show how you deal with this case. It's usually a lot clearer than trying to describe it in text.

Comment: @Bakli Why on earth would you not say that you have already tried the suggested solution?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but that is why I only mention below line of code `my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');` that needs be handle.Because while debugging the same system is went into halt mode and it is not comming back from this.

Comment: @Bakli Is the process still running on the server? Try killing it. There is some piece of information missing here. If you try to run the script at the command prompt, does it work then? I.e. is it the parsing of the file that is the problem, or something webserver related?

Answer (score 1):

This is often how one handles `die`s in functions:

```
eval {   # try block
    my $workbook = $parser->parse("file.xlsx");
    # ...other operations
};

if($@) { # catch
    print "$@";   # print the message
}
```

Comment: While using this, I am getting internal server 500 in web browser.Do we require any library ?

Comment: @Bakli I'm sorry but no. An internal 500 in the browser sounds odd though. Are you sure that doesn't come from the server? Anyway, did my answer answer your question and make it possible to catch the exception?

Comment: 500 internal error comes from printing "Got exception" before the header, maybe.

Comment: @TLP Yes, that sounds possible. "500" most probably comes from the server so I don't think a cgi generated header has anything to do with it. Anyway, if the message in the exception is supposed to be interpreted by a browser one should of course _not_ add `"Got exception: "` there :-) I removed that part just to make sure.

Comment: I noticed a downvote and I'm curious if this is _not_ how to catch `die`s etc? This is what I've used with many other perl OOP frameworks in the past but ... things may have changed, so my question is honest.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wrote a large CGI based Perl webservice a long time ago, and 500 was a common error when the wrong output was printed. Usually it was errors. I think that Perl's CGI module is deprecated nowadays, or something like that.

Comment: @TLP Aha, I see. Good to know. I don't use perl much nowadays and have never really used CGI much. I should refrain from guessing :-) I'm still curious about the downvote I got. Do you know if there's a better way to catch the exception-like `die`s used in many frameworks?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sometimes educated guesses are helpful. :)

Comment: I guess so! :-D

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, I do not know why your answer was downvoted. I've not used the exception catching logic much. I do know there is something called try/catch, which is a module sometimes used for this purpose. Also croak is something to that effect, but I am not too familiar with it.

Comment: @TLP Yeah, that's a new thingy. I've read about it but never used it. I looked it up now and it seems it was merged (promoted from experimental I guess) 5 months ago.

Comment: thank you for your time,I checked after removing print. but still that cgi file is not accepting eval in code.If I removed eval then I am not getting 500,but if I add eval then I am getting 500

Comment: @Bakli I just enabled CGI scripts on my server and wrote a perl GCI script containing an `eval { ... }; if($@) { ... }` combo just like in my answer - and it worked just fine. Could you edit your question and put a [mre] in it?

Comment: Have you also taken a look in your http server's error log? I noticed that while setting up GCI, I had managed to misconfiguring it, resulting in "_500 Internal Server Error - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request._" and the error log gave me hints about what the problems was.

Comment: @TedLyngmo When I wrote my CGI project, I found it useful to redirect the cgi script STDERR to a local log file, so I could easily find the latest and relevant error messages.